# hampton bay ceiling fan quit working

Tags: electrical

my ceiling fan is hard wired with no switch only operated by remote control.it stopped working so I replaced the remote control,which worked for about a year.i opened the remote and could find no problems...checked/replaced battery,still no go.could the problem be in the fan itself?the unit is approx. 12 years old.the light on the remote works but is dim....

Comment: Are you looking for advice about the remote unit in the fan (that can be replaced) or about the prospect of adding a wall switch or some other solution?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds quite simple. Replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Try plugging it in directly to your electric supply, without the remote in between. If it runs at full speed, it's probably okay and the remote is bad.

If it still won't run, you can probably try to replace the fan motor (or assorted electrics).

But then, at that point, it's a 12-year old fan with a bum motor, arguably the most important mechanical part. Full replacement is probably cheaper, quicker and will probably give you a more efficient appliance.